# How to bind a TextArea to a String to create a Terminal

Tags: string, binding, javafx

My goal is to **create a terminal**. To do so I use a `TextArea`, I receive *data* that I put in a `StringProperty`, and then I want to **bind this `StringProperty` to my `TextArea`**.

**Here's what I do** :

In the class that *receives the data* :

```
StringProperty sendData = new SimpleStringProperty();
WHEN I RECEIVE DATA : sendData.set(Arrays.toString(strings));
```

In the class that *contains the TextArea* :

```
@FXML private TextArea consoleTextArea = new TextArea();
public void setLiaison (StringProperty textRecu){
        consoleTextArea.textProperty().bind(textRecu);
}
```

In a third class I initialise everything, and call `setLiaison(sendData);`

But this doesn't work :

- I have nothing that displays in my TextArea when the StringProperty is modified.
- Even if it was displayed, I would want the next change on the `StringProperty` to be written in the TextArea below the first line, not erase it and write again, how could I do that?

Thanks.

**EDIT** : *Complete Controller Class* :

```
public class ConsoleViewController implements Initializable{

    @FXML private VBox consoleVBox;
    @FXML private HBox titleHBox;
    @FXML private Label consoleLabel;
    @FXML private Button closeButton;
    @FXML private TextArea consoleTextArea;


    public void setLiaison (StringProperty textRecu){
        consoleTextArea.textProperty().bind(
                   Bindings.concat(consoleTextArea.getText()).concat("\n").concat(textRecu.get()));

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have nothing that displays in my TextArea when the StringProperty is modified.

You are not supposed to initialize a control reference using `new` keyword, which are already annotated with `@FXML`. These fields are initialized when the FXML is loaded. Just use :

```
@FXML 
private TextArea consoleTextArea;
```

> I would want the next change on the StringProperty to be written in the TextArea below the first line, not erase it and write again.

You can set the append Text to the TextArea by using :

```
consoleTextArea.appendText(textRecu.getText()+"\n");
```

Comment: The problem is, that consoleTextArea is NULL in my setLiaison function, I can only use it in the initialize function ... :/

Comment: Read the first part of my answer.

Comment: It's after I apply your answer that consoleTextArea is NULL, I don't know why but I can only use the consoleTextArea in the function initialize() , and can't create other function that use it in my controller ...

Comment: Can you post the complete controller class? And what do you in the `third class` that you initialise.

Comment: I 'll up date my post, in the third class, I just instanciate everything, and call myController.setLiaison(sendData)

Comment: My wild guess would be that you are constructing a new instance of the Controller by using **new** keyword. Are you extracting the controller from the `FXMLLoader` instance by using `loader.getController()` ?

Comment: I already told you, use `loader.getController()`. If you need further assistance, please add the code for the third class.

Comment: Really thanks fr your help but the concat doesn't work, but the bind is now correct.

Comment: Just make sure `textRecu` has data in it.

Comment: It has, actually, consoleTextArea.textProperty().bind(textRecu); works fine , but of course keep erasing the text